# LINQ Lambda only select if exists

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I am using NHibernate which is abstracted away using Respositories and services.  We are not allowed to Lazy Load properties, so they have to be selected in the query.

My issue is that I am trying to get the most recent response number from the Answers table, but in many cases the object might not exist, so I am stuck with getting Null Reference exceptions, or "Code should be unreachable" exceptions.

Here is what i'm doing with the approprtiate sections commented.
.

```
var leaders = 
    _storeService.GetAll()
                 .Where( p => p.Id.Equals(storeId) && p.Employees.Any() )
                 .SelectMany(p => p.Employees)
                 .Select(emp => new
                  {
                      LeaderId = emp.Id,
                      LeaderFirstName = emp.FirstName,
                      LeaderLastName = emp.LastName,
                      Followers = emp.Followers
                                     .Select(followers => new

{
    followers.FollowerEmployee.Id,
    followers.FollowerEmployee.FirstName,                    
    followers.FollowerEmployee.LastName,
    DepartmentName = followers.FollowerEmployee.Department.Name,

    //Problem Area
    AssessmentResponse = followers.FollowerEmployee
                                  .Answers
                                  .First( a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary )
                                  .Answer
                                  .Number
                                  //Null Reference Exception                                        
} )

} ).ToList();
```

I've probably tried 15 iterations of this, not always using .First but sometimes .Single

I don't have access to the repository pattern or any of the NHibernate queries.  Is there a way to avoid this null reference exception with LINQ?  I can't lazy load, so it's a bit of an issue.

Comment: FirstOrDefault maybe?

Comment: I've tried FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault, Single, First, Take(1)... Null Reference Exception or "Code Should Be Unreachable".

Comment: The indentation here is making this *really* hard to read...

Comment: The null reference is coming from trying to get the Number property of answer? Could you do a where count is greater than 1?

Comment: Which property is giving you the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: .Answers might not exist on an employee, also even if it does there might be one that is primary.

Answer (score 2):

In EF/Linq-2-Sql, this can be made to work by casting to a nullable value since the underlying SQL does null-coalescing:

```
AssessmentResponse = (int?)followers.FollowerEmployee.Answers
    .First(a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary).Answer.Number
```

I'm not sure what the behavior would be in NHibernate but it's worth a try. If the Number property is already nullable, you could try coalescing it:

```
AssessmentResponse = (int?)followers.FollowerEmployee.Answers
    .First(a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary).Answer.Number ?? some default value
```

Finally, you could always do an explicity check:

```
AssessmentResponse = followers.FollowerEmployee.Answers.Any(a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary)
    ? followers.FollowerEmployee.Answers.First(a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary).Answer.Number ?? some default value
     : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
AssessmentResponse = followers.FollowerEmployee
                              .Answers
                              .First( a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary )
                              .Answer
                              .Number
                              //Null Reference Exception
```

Try this:

```
AssessmentResponse = followers.FollowerEmployee
                              .Where(a=>a.Answers != null && a.Answers
                                                              .Where(a=>a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary)
                                                              .Count > 0)
                              .Answers
                              .FirstOrDefault( a => a.Answer.Question.IsPrimary )
                              .Answer
                              .Number
                              //Null Reference Exception
```